# Variable precicion arithmetic for symbolic integral in Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, arbitrary-precision

I am trying to calculate some integrals that use very high power exponents. An example equation is:

```
(-exp(-(x+sqrt(p)).^2)+exp(-(x-sqrt(p)).^2)).^2 ...
./( exp(-(x+sqrt(p)).^2)+exp(-(x-sqrt(p)).^2)) ...
/ (2*sqrt(pi))
```

where `p` is constant (1000 being a typical value), and I need the integral for x=[-inf,inf]. If I use the `integral` function for numeric integration I get `NaN` as a result. I can avoid that if I set the limits of the integration to something like [-20,20] and a low `p` (<100), but ideally I need the full range.

I have also tried setting `syms x` and using `int` and `vpa`, but in this case `vpa` returns:

```
1.0 - 1.0*numeric::int((1125899906842624*(exp(-(x - 10*10^(1/2))^2) - exp(-(x + 10*10^(1/2))^2))^2)/(3991211251234741*(exp(-(x - 10*10^(1/2))^2) + exp(-(x + 10*10^(1/2))^2)))
```

without calculating a value. Again, if I set the limits of the integration to lower values I do get a result (also for low `p`), but I know that the result that I get is wrong – e.g., if x=[-100,100] and p=1000, the result is >1, which should be wrong as the equation should be asymptotic to 1 (or alternatively the codomain should be [0,1) ).

Am I doing something wrong with `vpa` or is there another way to calculate high precision values for my integrals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're doing something that makes solving symbolic problems more difficult and less accurate. The variable `pi` is a floating-point value, not an exact symbolic representation of the fundamental constant. In Matlab symbolic math code, you should always use `sym('pi')`. You should do the same for any other special numeric values, e.g., `sqrt(sym('2'))` and `exp(sym('1'))`, you use or they will get converted to an approximate rational fraction by default (the source of strange large number you see in the code in your question). For further details, I recommend that you read through the documentation for the [`sym`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html) function.

Applying the above, here's a runnable example:

```
syms x;
p = 1000;
f = (-exp(-(x+sqrt(p)).^2)+exp(-(x-sqrt(p)).^2)).^2./(exp(-(x+sqrt(p)).^2)...
    +exp(-(x-sqrt(p)).^2))/(2*sqrt(sym('pi')));
```

Now `vpa(int(f,x,-100,100))` and `vpa(int(f,x,-1e3,1e3))` return exactly `1.0` (to 32 digits of precision, see below).

Unfortunately, `vpa(int(f,x,-Inf,Inf))`, does not return an answer, but a call to the underlying MuPAD function [`numeric::int`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/numeric-int.html). As I explain in [this answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/16001/4474), this is what can happen when `int` cannot obtain a result. Normally, it should try to evaluate the the integral numerically, but your function appears to be ill-defined at ±∞, resulting in divide by zero issues that the variable precision quadrature methods can't handle well. You can evaluate the integral at wider bounds by increasing the variable precision using the [`digits`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/digits.html) function (just remember to set `digits` back to the default of 32 when done). Setting `digits(128)` allowed me to evaluate `vpa(int(f,x,-1e4,1e4))`. You can also more efficiently evaluate your integral over a wider range via `2*vpa(int(f,x,0,1e4))` at lower effective digits settings.

If your goal is to see exactly how much less than one `p = 1000` corresponds to, you can use something like `vpa(1-2*int(f,x,0,1e4))`. At `digits(128)`, this returns

```
0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000086457415971094118490438229708839420392402555445545519907545198837816908450303280444030703989603548138797600750757834260181259102
```

Applying [`double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/double.html) to this shows that it is approximately `8.6e-89`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I have another one though: (-7*exp(-(x+7*sqrt(p/21)).^2) -5*exp(-(x+5*sqrt(p/21)).^2) -3*exp(-(x+3*sqrt(p/21)).^2) -exp(-(x+sqrt(p/21)).^2)+7*exp(-(x-7*sqrt(p/21)).^2) +5*exp(-(x-5*sqrt(p/21)).^2) +3*exp(-(x-3*sqrt(p/21)).^2) +exp(-(x-sqrt(p/21)).^2)).^2./(exp(-(x+7*sqrt(p/21)).^2) + exp(-(x+5*sqrt(p/21)).^2) +  exp(-(x+3*sqrt(p/21)).^2) +exp(-(x+sqrt(p/21)).^2) + exp(-(x-7*sqrt(p/21)).^2) +  exp(-(x-5*sqrt(p/21)).^2) + exp(-(x-3*sqrt(p/21)).^2) +exp(-(x-sqrt(p/21)).^2))/(8*21*sqrt(sym('pi'))) and on this one for p=0.001 Matlab runs endlessly. Any ideas?

Comment: Two things to try. `0.001` does not have an exact floating-point representation. The symbolic math engine appears to properly recognize it this decimal value as `1/1000`, but if you instead set `p = 1/sym(1000)` (probably a good idea in general), it appears that the equations are manipulated differently. You can also try setting `p = 1/vpa(1000)`. I was able to get the same result from `vpa(int(f,x,-Inf,Inf))` in both cases for this example.